# How to scale a square grid to any phone's dimensions

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hi I'm trying to make a square 8x8 grid on a canvas. I've managed to make a grid, but it turns out to be rectangular, but for the game I'm making it needs to be square. How do I change my code to make it a square grid scaled to the phone.

```
float testWidth = (getWidth() - 16f) / 9f;
float testHeight = (getHeight() - 16f) / 9f;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(padding + testWidth* i, padding, padding
                    + testWidth * i, testHeight* 8+padding, dark);
            canvas.drawLine(padding,  padding+testHeight* i, testWidth* 8
                    + padding, padding+testHeight* i, dark);
        }
```

EDIT: I can now make a square grid, but I don't know how to center the grid into the middle of the phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to take the shortest of the two (Width or Height) and use that to build the grid upon. (So your grid can fit on the screen)

Something like...:

```
float gridSide = 0;
if (getWidth() > getHeight()) {
  gridSide = getHeight();
}
else {
  gridSide = getWidth();
}
```

Simpler logic provided by [appsroxcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107118/appsroxcom):

```
float gridSide = Math.min(testWidth(), testHeight());
```

Use **gridSide** as the total length *and* total width of the grid

Comment: Simpler logic: float cellSize = Math.min(testWidth, testHeight);

Comment: ahhh ofcourse! Thank you. One more question. This means that the grid takes up 3/4 of the canvas, with the bottom 1/4 completely blank. How would I get the grid in the center of the canvas?

Comment: Offset the view by ABS(height-width)/2