# I've created an 8x8 grid, but how can I center it?

Tags: android

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sc);
```

I've then added my canvas class to this container, but my grid is in the top left corner, i.e there is  big space below the grid and I would like to know how to center the grid. This is my code to draw the grid.

```
float testWidth = (getWidth() - 16f) / 9f;
float testHeight = (getHeight() - 16f) / 9f;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    canvas.drawLine(testWidth* i, 0 , testWidth * i, testWidth* 8, dark);
    canvas.drawLine(0,  testWidth* i, testWidth* 8, testWidth* i, dark);
}
```

Do I use gravity/margin in the xml file?

Comment: you use testWidth for both X and Y in the drawlines, your not using testHeight, I know its not an answer to centering just an observation, but using testHeight for your Y will then make the grid be the whole of the getHeight(), though the grid will not be square.

Comment: @Dampsquid He definitely wants it square, judging by his [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138834/how-to-scale-a-square-grid-to-any-phones-dimensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it works for you.

```
    float testWidth = (getWidth() - 16f) / 9f;
    float testHeight = (getHeight() - 16f) / 9f;
    float size = Math.min(testWidth, testHeight);
    float offsetW = (getWidth() - size*8) / 2;
    float offsetH = (getHeight() - size*8)  /2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(offsetW + size*i, 
                        offsetH, 
                        offsetW + size*i, 
                        offsetH + size*8, 
                        dark);
        canvas.drawLine(offsetW,  
                        offsetH + size* i, 
                        offsetW + size* 8, 
                        offsetH + size* i, 
                        dark);
    }
```

The code is not tested. The idea is to provide horizontal and vertical offset to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gravity = "center"` in the XML file of the PARENT view. In that case, all children of the view will be centered.